# Grails Filter - Getting access to the servletRequest and servletResponse

Tags: grails, grails-filters

What is the proper way to get access to the servletRequest and servletResponse from a Grails Filter.

Not sure where these get passed in due to the builder syntax.

```
def filters = {

    all(controller:"*", action:"*") {
        before = {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's in the manual: UPDATED: [7.2.1.1 Variables and Scopes](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#variablesAndScopes)

> Filters support all the common properties available to controllers and tag libraries, plus the application context:
>
> - request - The HttpServletRequest object
> - response - The HttpServletResponse object

So just use `request` and `response` in your closures.